# Count number of events per hour in a time-serie - Python

Tags: python-3.x, time-series

I have this date-time attribute from which i want to create its appropriate time series counting the number of  events per hour :

```
ID  Date-time
1   31/12/2017 22:55
2   31/12/2017 22:27
3   31/12/2017 22:17
4   31/12/2017 21:55
5   31/12/2017 20:48
6   31/12/2017 11:03
7   31/12/2017 09:58
8   31/12/2017 09:52
9   31/12/2017 09:16
10  31/12/2017 08:11
```

I want to obtain  :

```
ID  Date-time        Events
1   31/12/2017 22:00,3
2   31/12/2017 21:00,1
3   31/12/2017 20:00,1
4   31/12/2017 19:00,0
5   31/12/2017 18:00,0
6   31/12/2017 17:00,0
7   31/12/2017 16:00,0
8   31/12/2017 15:00,0
9   31/12/2017 14:00,0
10  31/12/2017 13:00,0
11  31/12/2017 12:00,0
12  31/12/2017 11:00,0
13  31/12/2017 10:00,0
14  31/12/2017 09:00,3
15  31/12/2017 08:00,1
```

Is there a simple way to perform this task in Python ?

Lionel

Comment: Is there any reason behind skipping 10:00 and having two 19:00s in your output?  Also, is ID a column or the name of your index?

Comment: Hi @DSM. In deed there is an error in my post : 10:00 must be present and there is only one 19:00 in my output (I will edit my post). ID is the name of my index.